# Animating no-wrap in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have box that has some text in it that has no-wrap applied to it, forcing it to one line with ellipsis.  When a user hovers over it, I would like to remove the no-wrap property and have the box smoothly expand to the correct height.  This works by animating the max-height property, but the animation does not work when collapsing the box.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <p class='para'>
        This is some paragraph text that will wrap around because it's so long.
    </p>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    max-height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
    transition: all 2s linear;}

.para {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;}

.wrapper:hover {
    max-height:500px; }

.wrapper:hover .para {
    white-space: normal;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schiem/xk0hx24L/)

The cause of the non animated collapse is due to the text wrap jumping back down faster than the animation.  Is there a way to get the desired animation in pure CSS?  If not, is there an efficient way to do it in jQuery?

Comment: No...that's not an animatable property.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know I can't directly animate it, I'm more wondering if I can animate another property (like max-height) to make it look like it's being animated, as per the rest of the question.